# Alternative to UIImage's imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimage

I built an app for 4.x which should be deployed for all iPhones 3.0-4.x. I realized that the imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation method is only available in 4.0 and later. Any alternative for 3.x? For reference:

```
Creates and returns an image object with the specified scale and orientation factors.
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
```

My current usage:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed: @"arrow.png"] CGImage] scale:1.2 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

The scale is static (i.e. I never change it) so I might scale the image through photoshop instead but the orientation remains a necessity in my application.

Thanks!

Comment: check it http://paulsolt.com/2010/09/ios-converting-uiimage-to-rgba8-bitmaps-and-back/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the scale, rotate (translate) with CGContext functions. Then you can use...

```
CGImageRef CGBitmapContextCreateImage (
   CGContextRef c
);
```

and

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage
```